# how to resize widgets on a genymotion emulator?

Tags: android, widget, genymotion

I've just installed the genymotion emulator for android studio on a mac. When I launch an app all the widgets are too small. They're fine on a real phone. Is it something with the setting of the phone? It's not just my application...all the hard coded app are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly due to a wrong usage of the size units on your layouts. You should use `dp` and not `px` to define your widgets sizes.

If you want a deeper lesson about this topic checkout the new Google course on Udacity: [Android Design for Developers](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-design-for-developers--ud862)